# How to lock app to portrait mode as user preference

Tags: android, autorotate

I know how to lock an app to portrait mode [forever](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6581120):

```
<activity
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:name=".MyActivity"></activity>
```

I now want to make this a user preference. That is, instead of the user checking/unchecking `Settings > Display > Auto-rotate screen` for the **entire** phone, I want to have a similar checkbox for my application only.

How do I do that programmatically?

Comment: Have you tried using the checkbox? If it's true, use `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
`

Comment: @MrYanDao I didn't know about this [setRequestedOrientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation%28int%29) method. I think that's exactly what I was looking for. I'll check this out and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5584244), I came up with the following:

```
 private void doLock(boolean locked) {
        if (locked) {
            int o = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            if (o == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);             
            else if (o == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);              
        } 
        else {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
        }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also specify this in the AndroidManifest.xml as:

```
 <activity 
        android:name=".activityName" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```